# Easy way to retrieve data from a javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, database

At https://www.conzoom.eu/find-dig-selv/?default there is a form to enter an address and a postcode, when you search you get a code; A1, D3, E2 etc defining which segment this address is in.. I have a lot of addresses in an excel sheet of my customers that I would like to look up - is there an easier way than doing this manually?

Comment: JavaScript will not do all this for you, JavaScript can obtain the input values and send them to the server, which you'll need to communicate with your spreadsheet using a different language, such as Java.

Comment: Something like this: 1. Parse your data (from CSV, for example). 2. Loop through array. 3. CURL.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) might be what you are looking for. It is made to simulate a user on a website, so it can the inputs, read the outputs, and wait for the site to be ready before entering the next address.

The tricky part is about reading the excel sheet, depending on its format. But you can always write a macro to make the input more "readable".

Comment: Cool, thats awesome.. Ill check out Selenium :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible to do this in Javascript if the data can be moved to a format that the Javascript on the page can parse.

This is not best solution, but it is an approach I have taken in the past when the web server can only server static files, no server side processing.

From what your question suggests the data set is this may not be a practical solution, due to its size and complexity.

If the data was something like POSTCODE, LOCATION_CODE and there was a one to one mapping such as all postcodes starting with MK had a LOCATION_CODE of 83 then the data can be serialised into JSON or XML(JSON prefered).

Now when the user enters the postcode on the form the Javascript retrieves the data from the server as a static file and parses the results. Compares the users inputed POSTCODE against the data and returns a corresponding LOCATION_CODE.

This only works for simple data that changes very infrequently. Alternatively you need a server backend that will connect either to your excel spreadsheet (not good practice) or to a central database with the logic running to perform the search. This logic will need something like @Todd Motto suggested Java or any number of technologies such as C#, PHP, perl

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for an awesome reply!

My technical skills is insufficient to comprehend everything you wrote though, so I might check out Stiltorik's suggestion and see if I can make that work!